# how to know what sql statements is running in a connection

Tags: mysql, rds

I dont know if this is the right SO to post this question.

We are using aws for our rds server mysql for our backend database. What I would want to know is that the sql statements run by those connections using workbench or existing tools amazon have or any tools out there regardless if it is free or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql, you can get all running queries by this:

```
mysql>show full processlist;
```

You can also get this information from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA PROCESSLIST` table or the `mysqladmin processlist` command.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Workbech you can see sql statement of running connection on `Client Connections` tab in SQL IDE, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-client-connections.html